# Bootstrap lists inside panel are not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list

I'm creating the menu of a page in bootstrap 3.
This is my panel I have cretaed.[image]
 Here is my code of a panel I created:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel mepanelo">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4 big_list">
          <ul class="list1">
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="figurini.php">Figurini</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="mezzi.php">Mezzi Militari</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="accessori.php">Accessori</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="strumenti.php">Strumenti</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 big_list">
          <ul class="list1  ">
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="fantasy.php">Fantasy</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="aerei.php">Aerei</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="ambientazioni.php">Ambientazioni</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="edizioni.php">Edizioni</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4  big_list">
          <ul class="list1">
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="busti.php">Busti</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="navi.php">Navi</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="colori.php">Colori</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="occasioni.php">Occasioni</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

This panel and the lists inside it are responsive but the problem is that when the page is in the size of  a tablet here is how the lists appear:
[image]
I don't want all that blank gray space there but I want all the elements to appear in 2 lists for tablet and not in one list. I proved something like hidden-sm but this hides the things. Is there a way to put all the eleemts which are in three lists just in 2 lists for tablet? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 big_list">` instead of `<div class="col-md-4 big_list">`

Comment: I checked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the class from col-md to col-sm

```
<div class="col-md-4 big_list">
```

to

```
<div class="col-sm-4 big_list">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide 3rd list only on tablet (small devices) and adjust elements of that list in other 2 lists and show that elements only on small devices. Read comments in code. And for bootstrap hidden and visible classes Check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="panel mepanelo">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 big_list">
          <ul class="list1">
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="figurini.php">Figurini</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="mezzi.php">Mezzi Militari</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="accessori.php">Accessori</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="strumenti.php">Strumenti</a>
            </li>
            <!-- follwing elements are hidden on all devices except small (tablets) -->
            <li class="hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg"> 
              <a class="btn" role="button" href="busti.php">Busti</a>
            </li>
            <li class="hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg"> 
              <a class="btn" role="button" href="navi.php">Navi</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 big_list">
          <ul class="list1  ">
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="fantasy.php">Fantasy</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="aerei.php">Aerei</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="ambientazioni.php">Ambientazioni</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="edizioni.php">Edizioni</a>
            </li>
            <!-- follwing elements are hidden on all devices except small (tablets) -->
            <li class="hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg"><a class="btn" role="button" href="colori.php">Colori</a>
            </li>
            <li class="hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg" ><a class="btn" role="button" href="occasioni.php">Occasioni</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm big_list"> <!-- hidden on small devices -->
          <ul class="list1">
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="busti.php">Busti</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="navi.php">Navi</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="colori.php">Colori</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" role="button" href="occasioni.php">Occasioni</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem is you are not including the bootstrap engine. Please see to it that you have properly linked your bootstrap files. Once that is done, this code should work fine.

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 big_list">
```